# Why does this series diverge? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{4n-1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

So taking my original problem: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{4n-1}$

I treated it like a limit problem as took the sum to be $\frac{1}{4}$ and since that is $<1$ for this geometric series, I assumed it converges.  But it diverges and I don't really understand why.

We just started learning series this week and I'm having a little trouble catching on to the various reasons why some things converge and diverge.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are conflating the limit of the terms of the series with a root or ratio test; and also conflating it with the value of the series.  These three things are in general all different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails the $n$-th term test, since

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n - 1}{4n - 1} = \frac{1}{4} \ne 0$$

Morally, this series just keeps adding up $\frac{1}{4}$ over and over again, ad infinitum - so it cannot converge.

So in this case, the limit of the *sequence* exists, while the limit of the sequence of partial sums does not.

Comment: I see!  So since this is the sum of my series, if it is not zero it is adding up the sum over and over.  If it is zero, then it is converging to a number?

Comment: @inquisitor If $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, it is **not** necessary that the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. The harmonic series is an example of this.